# How do I change the property of a clicked element which shares its class with many other elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the color of the option that I clicked on and revert the other options back to their original state.

```js
let options = document.getElementsByClassName('about-me-submenu-option');

let i;
function unselectAll() {
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
  }
}

options.onclick = function() {
  unselectAll();
  this.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
}
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.option {
  background-color: #888;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
</div>
```

Or I put it in a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ou3sach0/

How do I select the element that was clicked? Is jQuery a better tool to do this with?

Comment: @trojo The element selected is automatically selected when is clicked. Changing the color the style.backgroundColor is well used but you have to get the event target. Like: function(event) and the event.target.style.backbackgroundColor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the `onclick` click handler to the array of elements instead of the elements themselves - you need to add a click handler to *each* of the elements, like this (see comments for more info):

```
// 1. Use querySelectorAll to get a NodeList that we can add the listener to
let options = document.querySelectorAll('.option');

// 2. loop through the options and add the event listener to each element
options.forEach(option => {
   option.addEventListener('click', function(){
      unselectAll();
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#333";  /* add colour to clicked element only */
   } );
});
```

**Working Example:**

```js
let options = document.querySelectorAll('.option');

let i;
function unselectAll() {
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        options[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
}

// loop through the options and add the event listener to each element
options.forEach(option => {
   option.addEventListener('click', function(){
      unselectAll();
      this.style.backgroundColor = "#333";  
   } );
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.option {
  background-color: #888;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Should you use the spread operator, i.e. `let options = [...document.querySelectorAll('.option')]`?

Comment: I would also make the cursor look like a pointer so it's obvious we are clicking on something -> cursor:pointer; ->  inside .option, otherwise amazing solution!

Comment: @AryanBeezadhur It's not necessary, as you can see in the snippet it works like this and it very much depends on what else the `options` array is going to be used for. We only have part of the OP's code so it's best to play it safe :)

Comment: @aljaz-code I'm not sure what you are trying to say?

Comment: .option:hover {
  background-color: #555; **cursor:pointer;**
} this part makes for the user helpful feedback that the area is clickable

Comment: @aljaz-code OK, I see your updated comment now - it just said ".option:hover { background-color: #555}" before you edited it so I wasn't sure what that meant :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add each option the proper event like so:

```js
let options = document.querySelectorAll('.container .option');

function unselectAll() {
  options.forEach(option => {
    option.style.backgroundColor = "";
  });
}

options.forEach(option => {
  option.addEventListener('click', event => {
    unselectAll();
    option.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
  })
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.option {
  background-color: #888;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
</div>
```

or use event bubbling that is using less events like so

```js
let options = document.querySelectorAll('.option');

function unselectAll() {
  options.forEach(option => {
    option.style.backgroundColor = "";
  });
}

const container = document.querySelector('.container');

container.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (!event.target in options) {
    return;
  }
  unselectAll();
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = "#333";
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 150px;
}

.option {
  background-color: #888;
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
}
.option:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
  <div class="option">Option</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with vanilla JS, but since you mentioned jQuery, here's my take:

CSS class

```
.option-clicked{background-color: #333;}
```

JS

```
$(".option").on("click", function(){
  $(".option").removeClass("option-clicked");
  $(this).addClass("option-clicked");
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hv0qnwsx/9/

Essentially everytime you click an ".option" element, the ".option-clicked" class is removed and then it's added to THIS particular ".option" that you clicked. Hope it's clear enough!